# Mapear Substring Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho o model `city(name, uf, province)` estou tentando implementar o método de pesquisa sunspot, mas estou conseguindo por parte:

```
# modelCity.rb
searchable do
  text :name 
end 

# controller City
unless params[:search] 
  @cities = City.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "name ASC")
else
  @search = City.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @cities = @search.results
end
```

Base de dados city:

```
1 Medianeira PR 3
2 Cascavel   PR 4
3 Cascavemat PR 3
```

Se eu digitar por exemplo "Cascavel" ele traz a busca certa, mas se eu digitar "Casca" eu quero que ele traga todas as cidades que tenha essas palavras relacionadas ao nome. Alguém sabe como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando um Banco de Dados SQL, você pode usar wildcards:

```
query = "CASCA"
City.where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
```

**Desta maneira, o framework já trata problemas como SQL Injection*

Comment: Apesar de funcionar acho que o OP quer uma solução para usar com o solr e não em sql.